# What is the difference between a background and foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service, background-service, foreground-service

I am currently writing my first Android application and I keep running into references to background and foreground services. Since I intend on using a service in my application I was hoping to get a clarification between the two and how they are used.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Perhaps this will answer your question:

> A started service can use the startForeground API to put the service
>   in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing
>   when low on memory. By default services are background, meaning that
>   if the system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to
>   display a large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too
>   much harm.

More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: How can you know if your service really started as foreground service? is there any trace in logcat?

Comment: Whether the service is in foreground or background depends on two factors: the service state and the way you started it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle

Answer (score 61):

**Foreground**: The process relies on onPause() and onResume()...i.e you play music player and pressing pause and play

**Background**: The process which runs without user interaction i.e receiving a message, incoming call, receiving mails, or setting alarms. The method used here is onStart() and onStop().

For example, check it on your phone. Create an alarm at 6:30am. When the system clock reaches 6:30am it fires. In order to kill the alarm service, just go to menu-->settings-->application-->Running service-->click stop service. It stops the alarm service even when your system reaches the time it won't fire.

Comment: Better to attach a link to the relevant official documentation, like this one: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 5):

`Foreground Service` is used when User is interaction with application and when `Service` is doing something visible to user. `Background Service` is used when even user close application (discard from recents) and when `Service` is doing something not visible to user like downloading data from server, load data from a `ContentProvider` etc.. And `Foreground Service` is less likely to be killed by system on low memory.