# Is there any way for Kivy app to continue working in background?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, parallel-processing, kivy

I am making an android app using kivy. I want my app should continue to run in background Even if I press minimize button of android. Is there any way to do so??

Comment: You can use an Android service to do this.

Comment: @inclement how to use android service can you tell me??

Answer (score 2):

If you mean minimize the app, add on_pause function to your App class:

```py
class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='hello')

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        #do something after reopening app
        pass
```

But, if you mean creating background process or service that continue running even you close your app, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321529/14073186).